# Support Multiple Bluetooth Profiles on a single BTLE system

Tags: bluetooth, btle, bluetooth-profile

I'm working on developing a health system that many different sensors can be plugged into, but may not have all or any of the supported devices attached at a given time. Ideally the system could advertise each of the associated profiles via BTLE, but I have a few questions about this solution that I can't seem to find a solid answer to.

1) Can a single system support multiple BTLE Profiles?

2) In order to support a profile, if the services and characteristics required by the profile need to be supported are supported is that enough? Each of the profile documents outlines some specific connection intervals and and I wasn't sure if this is a requirement or a suggested implementation.

3) Is it possible to modify the enabled profiles at run time as tools are connected to the base system, and if so will it have any affect on currently connected or paired devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can a single system support multiple BTLE Profiles?

Spec does not prohibit a single system support multiple BTLE profiles however most of them only support one profiles. The profile's definitions was weaken on BTLE but you can add more services on one profile.

> 2) In order to support a profile, if the services and characteristics
>   required by the profile need to be supported are supported is that
>   enough? Each of the profile documents outlines some specific
>   connection intervals and and I wasn't sure if this is a requirement or
>   a suggested implementation.

If both device and apps are developed by yourself, you may customize the service/characteristics.
It's a suggested contemplation, however if the word is "shall" then it is mandatory.

> 3) Is it possible to modify the enabled profiles at run time as tools
>   are connected to the base system, and if so will it have any affect on
>   currently connected or paired devices?

Surely you can dynamically add or remove service at run time. it does not affect the currently connected or paired device.